# How to extend an assembly from other assemblies in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-assembly

In my current assembly I have an Interface `IProcessor` that takes a type definition (using Mono.Cecil) and processes it "somehow".

The exact implementations of that interface are supposed to be in separate assemblies. So in order to find all implementations of `IProcessor`, I am looping over each assembly, searching sub classes and then call their process-method from the `ProcessingManager`.

But looping over every assembly is quite slow so I wondered if there might be some built-in feature to extend the functionality of `ProcessingManager` from outside of its assembly.

PS: My plan was to implement a similar behaviour as beans in spring boot where you can easily find all beans that implement a given interface. Only that in my case there are no beans but classes and they are in separate assemblies.

Comment: I assume you aren't caching the results of the interface search and are looping each time you want to "process". Ideally you want to do the discovery early and cache the results. If you are using a DI/IoC framework, usually they will have this feature built in (assembly discovery and caching). Some don't but most of the main ones do.

Comment: @Charleh Actually I am using Unity. Not sure if I can add DI/IoC (which I never used before). The search for processors runs everytime something compiles and I do not cache it yet because I might add processors which should be added during compilation

Comment: I assume you are using unity container and not talking about unity game engine? Can we clarify, are you actually dropping new libraries into a folder at runtime and having the application pick them up, are you compiling up front and need to discover types at compile time, or finally are you run-time compiling? They are 3 different scenarios so clarification would be helpful, there are different solutions for all 3.

Comment: searching for and constructing types with reflection may be risky, since it may fail if the type lacks a parameterless constructor. I would generally not expect things to break If I create a type that is never used anywhere. If you are unfamiliar with Dependency Injection containers I would recommend at least trying out the concept. It sounds like it may be applicable for your use case, but it is a bit difficult to tell without more details.

Comment: @JonasH I am very well familiar with the concept of dependency injection. And this is infact exactly what I am searching. I just dont know how to inject my dependencies (implementations of IProcessor) into another assembly. 
I will clarify my needs further in my next comment

Comment: @Charleh my plan is to publish multiple assets that all extend unity's functionality in some sort. All of them will include a core-assembly that runs only at *compile time*, reading the code that is to be compiled and lets it be modified by the other packages.
But since not every user will have all packages, I cannot know from the core-perspective which processors exist. This is why I first find them in all assemblies and then execute them one by one.

Comment: The way we used to do it was with a `IModule`-interface containing a `Register(IUnityContainer container)`-method. At startup we would search and create all modules, similarly as you seem to do, passing the container so each could register their types. This was for internal modules, so errors would be found fairly quickly. But it was somewhat prone to runtime errors due to missing types. But I think the best approach will depend on if you are loading assemblies at runtime or not, and if these assemblies are third or first party.

Comment: @JonasH this actually seems pretty similar to my approach. Luckily, I will most likely never load assemblies at runtime. All changes that the processors do will just be put into the compiled code.